# Google apps script for docs: Log text selection as string

Tags: string, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to return the words in a text selection as a string in google docs. I can't figure out how to return anything other than the entire body of text in an element, and it seems like the smallest element is a paragraph. I ned smaller.

Attempt 1:

```
function printSelection1 () {
var string = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getText();
Logger.log(string);
}
```

This returns the entire body of the document, rather than the selection, as a string.

Attempt 2:

```
function printSelection2 () {
var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
var string =selection.asString();
Logger.log(string);
}
```

Error message: "TypeError: selection.asString is not a function."

Attempt 3:

```
function printSelection4 () {
var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
var getelements =selection.getSelectedElements();
var string = getelements.toString();
Logger.log(string);
}
```

This returns the string "RangeElement," rather than the string of the selection itself.

I feel like I'm close. Or maybe I'm not?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected result from `I'm trying to return the words in a text selection as a string in google docs.`. In order to correctly understand your expected result, can you provide the sample input and output situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Document.getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getselection) to get the selected `Range` and [Range.getRangeElements()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range#getrangeelements) to get the elements in the `Range`, including any `Text` elements therein.

You are saying that you want to get "only the individual words that are selected." To get text that spans just a portion of an element, such as in the start and end of the selection, use [RangeElement.isPartial()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element#isPartial()) together with `RangeElement.getStartOffset()` and `RangeElement.getEndOffsetInclusive()`. When `isPartial()` returns `false`, you can use `RangeElement.getElement().asText().getText()` to get all the text in the element.

Here's an example of how to do this:

```js
function printSelection() {
  const selectedText = getSelectedText();
  console.log(selectedText ? `The selected text is "${selectedText}".` : `No text is selected.`);
}

/**
* Gets the currently selected text in a document.
*
* @param {DocumentApp.Range} range Optional. The document range where to get text. Defaults to currently selected text.
* @return {String} The text in range joined with newlines, or an empty string when the range does not contain text.
*/
function getSelectedText(range = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection()) {
  const result = [];
  if (range) {
    range.getRangeElements().forEach(rangeElement => {
      if (rangeElement.isPartial()) {
        const startIndex = rangeElement.getStartOffset();
        const endIndex = rangeElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();
        result.push(rangeElement.getElement().asText().getText().substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1));
      } else {
        const element = rangeElement.getElement();
        if (element.editAsText) {
          const elementText = element.asText().getText();
          if (elementText) {
            result.push(elementText);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
  return result.length ? result.join('\n') : '';
}
```

This example is based on the partially outdated [Docs quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/editors/docs/quickstart/translate).

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
function getSelectedText() {
  var text = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
    .getSelection() 
    .getRangeElements()
    .map((element) => element.getElement().asText().getText())
    .join(" ");

  Logger.log(text);
}
```

Comment: This logs all of the text in the selected paragraph. I'm looking to log only the individual words that are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this suffice:

```
function printSelection() {
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (selection) {
    var range = selection.getRange();
    var string = range.getText();
    Logger.log(string);
  } else {
    Logger.log("No text is selected.");
  }
}
```

EDIT: Judging by the error, it seems that getRange() is not available for the seleciton object...

You can try to use the `getStartOffset()` and `getEndOffset()`:

```
function printSelection() {
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (selection) {
    var startIndex = selection.getStartOffset();
    var endIndex = selection.getEndOffset();
    var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var string = document.getText().substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    Logger.log(string);
  } else {
    Logger.log("No text is selected.");
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and got an error message: "TypeError: selection.getRange is not a function"

Comment: I edited the answer and added another suggestion that you might try with getStartOffset and getEndOffset mehtods.

Comment: I tried the edit and got error message: TypeError: selection.getStartOffset is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous answers, improved for multi paragraph selection :

```
function printSelect() {
  
  const r = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();

  if (!r) {
    return;
  }

  const tab = r.getRangeElements();
  var output = "";

  for (let x = 0; x < tab.length; x++) {

    let start = tab[x].getStartOffset();
    let end = tab[x].getEndOffsetInclusive();
    let selection = tab[x].getElement().getText().substring(start, end);

    output += selection || "\n\n"; //if selection is null == paragraph, so add double \n
  }
  Logger.log(output);
}
```